# Reading degree symbol from .txt file with scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a master program for my simulator flying. I get briefings in a .txt file, and I am attempting to read the file with a scanner. The .txt file contains a degree symbol, and this causes the scanner to not to read the entire file.

```
 public static String[] ConvertFile(String FileName){
    ArrayList<String> FileArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count = 0; 

    try{
        Scanner file =  new Scanner( new File ("C:\ <File Location>" + FileName));
        while(file.hasNextLine()){
            count++;
            String Line = file.nextLine());
            System.out.printf("%3d: %s %n", count, Line );
            System.out.println(count);

        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println("File Not Found.");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Ive put the line in queston below (Line 23)

```
COND:    140475 LB // RWY DRY // +14°C  Q1021  270/09  // LMT: OBS(B)
```

Note that the output gives the first 16 lines of the txt file when there are 726 lines. I know its the degree symbol because when I edit the txt and remove the degree symbols, the program outputs all the lines.

Comment: So it crashes because of the degree symbol?

Comment: What happens when you get to the symbol? Does it crash, does `file.hasNextLine()` start returning `false`? Are there any other degree symbols before this that are read, or is this the first?

Comment: It doesn't crash it prints the first 16 lines of the txt file but there are 726 lines. sorry, I wasn't clear about that. I know this is the problem because when I edit the txt file and remove the symbols the scanner is able to print all the lines.

Comment: What **'charset' (encoding)** does the file use for this non-ASCII character (and any others)? Is that your JVM's default charset, which the 1-arg ctor for `Scanner` uses? If not, use the 2-arg ctor to specify the correct charset.

Comment: The first thing I'd try is delete that 16th line that it gets stuck on and see if it goes any further, or if 16 is the max it will do.

Comment: If I delete line 16 it stops at line 17 and I deleted line 17 and it stops at 18. If I delete the lines with the degree symbol the program prints all the lines. I think it's an encoding problem but I can't quite nail it down.

Comment: @TheSpaceWolf ITs should not be the degree symbol. Still, try what dave_thompson has suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interesting behavior. I tried to run your example and I got the same results, except for me, if I had a degree symbol on line 5 of my file, the program did not even want to display the first 4 lines. The exact reason behind this has something to do with character encoding and it would be interesting to find a detailed explanation with someone who has an insight into this.

After some digging around, it turns out that Java's `Scanner` uses the underlying platform's default character set. You can find out what your default character set is by using the following code:

```
System.out.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());
```

On my system, the message that was displayed was "UTF-8". I am currently using a Windows 10 system, and the text file that I created had a default character encoding of "ANSI". I would advise to make sure that the character encoding that your `Scanner` is using and the character encoding of your text file are the same.

Using Window's notepad application, I was able to change the character encoding from ANSI to UTF-8. Just click on "File" then "Save As..." and when the dialog box pops up, make sure that you choose "UTF-8" on the bottom in the "Encoding" box.

[image]

When I re-ran the example. The application was able to read every line successfully. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will need to remember to save my txt files with the UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

After a while of playing with this, a solution I came up without having to re-save the file in UTF-8 was to have the program read the file, then re-write it in UTF-8 in its own directory and read the file from the directory in the UTF-8 format